# ARM (Cortex-A8) High Speed Bus?

Tags: fpga, arm, memory, high-speed

I need to communicate from FPGA to ARM with about 16GBits/s...
Is there a Bus which I can use? Or how to solve this problem?

The FPGA receives data over LVDS. This data schould be post-processed in ARM (User can write some linux-based software to store the data on SSD)

btw. FPGA and ARM will be on the same board ;)

Comment: What ARM processor are you using that can even support 16 Gbps IO?

Comment: Dual-ported RAM?

Comment: That would be a 32-bit DDR interface at 250MHz. I wouldn't be at all surprised to find an ARM that can support it.

Comment: Even the RAM bandwidth on A8 is not that high.

Comment: Oh, you want to build your own _gaming computer_!? Really, what do you want to achieve? More information is needed to help you out here, because the plain specs you asked for are out of this world.

Comment: Given an ARM clock rate of 1GHz, that gives you one instruction per every 16 bits of data. There really isn't a lot of processing you're going to be doing with that.

Comment: For what length of time do you want to sustain this data rate? Indefinitely?

Comment: If *storage* is all you want to do, skip the processor and stream straight to the storage devices, with the processor only as supervisor.  You'll likely need to split the data across multiple drives and provide *large* fifo buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

16 GBits/sec on-board shouts PCIe to me.  Each lane is 2.5Gbit/s, so a x8 PCIe link should be sufficient.

Of course, as others note, what you are going to do with that data in an A8 is a whole other problem.  Writing it to SSD seems unlikely BTW - 2GByte/sec of disk bandwidth will tax 3 SATA 6Gbps links... Are there any ARM processors with several SATA ports?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of killing your poor ARM with your Gbps, stuff all that data into x32 DDR3 RAMs from the FPGA and let the ARM to get the data at its pace. Easy to say, I know.